# Importing React: Unexpected identifier 'React'. import call expects exactly one argument."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I am using React in Action by Manning Publications. The book uses React v. 16.0.0 and I have set up my dependencies in package.json to be identical to theirs. Their code says to import as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
```

But when I do, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'React'. import call expects exactly one argument.
```

I've scoured Stock Overflow for an answer but could not find anything about what the error means in the context of React. I have tried using React v. 16.4.2, the current version, 16.0.1, the version that the book uses, and v. 15.0.1. Nothing changes.

The closest Stack Overflow article I could find is asking the difference between the "import react" and "{ Component }" "from 'react'" portions of the import expression.

[image: import calls]

[image: error message]

Comment: What browser are you running this in?

Comment: Are you running this code in the browser directly, or jave you set up something like Babel, Webpack or a combination of them, or similar tools, to interpret your code?

Comment: What transpiler are you using?

Comment: Safari; not using a transpiler because I am not using JSX, in my current code--e.g., I am using React.createElement calls; no web pack or other tools.

When I use the official unpkg CDN for react rather than hosting it locally using NPM, everything works fine without the import statements. The issue is the book uses the prop-types library, which is no longer a core feature. When I use the CDN for prop-types, I get other warnings: "Warning: Failed prop type: Comment: prop type `content` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `undefined`."

Comment: If I don't use the prop-types CDN, it just throws errors that propTypes is an undefined variable.

Comment: Oddly,  I just added Babel. I didn't add web pack. And its transpiring the code as normal. But now I'm getting the error: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require"

Answer (score 0):

You need some Modules or bundler like Webpack.You cannot excecute it

Comment: Please give some steps and examples.